# How I will get line in string array that start with # tag and will show as a heading. Using Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I update my question.

How I will get line that start with # tag and will show as a heading. Before next # tag all data will be show as content of the heading.

Now I have getting file data in label.
How I will do work with this. Using Xamarin C#.

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html

Comment: Download/read the html file into a string and assign that to the Text property

Comment: Thank you!   That one is text file. downloaded and Read the data asynchronously.

Comment: I want when sentences start with <H>  that line will bold.

Comment: You will need to process the text before displaying: identify each header line, remove the `<H>`, add begin- and endtags for "bold" (for example `<h1>...</h1>` or `<strong>...</strong>`) (assuming HTML display)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I am not sure if OP is _actually_ having an HTML file.

Comment: @OP Is that a custom markup language you are encountering, there?

Comment: @Fildor no, the file doesn't appear to be HTML. But the first link shows how to use formatting *if* the text is *shown* as HTML. I built on that

Comment: I have a txt file on server that have text data. Now I'm getting all text data in a label. I would like to when # tag start that line will bold.  After new line all content will be show as a paragraph before next # tag. 
Then repeat again this same things for all content of text file. This is mobile application and I'm using Xamarin with C#.  Just for example changed <H> to #.  @HansKeﬆing   Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer. This is what I wanted to do.

```
public string UrlFileText { get; set; }
public string[] contentList { get; set; }

WebClient client = new WebClient();          
UrlFileText = client.DownloadString(url);

contentList = UrlFileText.Split("#");
for (int i = 1; i < contentList.Length; i++)
{              
    string[] contentItems = contentList[i].Split("\n", 2);                
    Console.WriteLine("Printing Header of content... \n");
    Console.WriteLine(contentItems[0], "\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Printing content of Content... \n");
    Console.WriteLine(contentItems[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have different text Type in label, you can try spantext, code like:

```
  <Label FontSize="16" >
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="Hello " x:Name="text1"/>
                        <Span Text="World " FontAttributes="Bold"  x:Name="text2"/>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
```

As for how to change the specific sentence, you can get the span text in code behind, and handle it there on **Onappearing** method.